# npm -g adds package to C:\usr\local instead of C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm

Tags: node.js, npm, ionic-framework

I'm trying to working with ionic framework but i get stuck when install ionic via npm

```
npm install -g ionic
```

I try $ ionic but it always show "ionic is not recognized as an internal or external command" error.
Then I found that ionic was added into C:\usr\local instead of C:\Users{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm.

I's using Windows 8.1 and I also add C:\Users{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm into PATH and restart machine.
Please help me.

Comment: If you type `set` at the command prompt, do you see `HOME` set or just `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` set?

Comment: hi @mscdex this is what i get when i type set at the cmd [link](http://i.imgur.com/7OevRQK.png) It doesn't show HOME just HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH. How can i fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can temporally fix this issue by copy all folders , files in  C:\usr\local instead and paste into  C:\Users{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm.

But I still wonder why I get this issue.
Thanks guys.